# How to load image from static file from a javascript function using django

Tags: javascript, django

I have a problem when trying to get a picture from my static files, but from a javascript finction.

Here is my code for javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url_1 = '{% static "assets/img/stolovi/2.jpg" %}';

    function addimage1() {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = url_1;
        img.height = 50;
        img.width = 50;
        img.draggable = true;
        //optionally set a css class on the image
        var class_name = "foo";
        img.setAttribute("class", class_name);

        document.getElementById("myDiagramDiv").appendChild(img);
        //document.body.appendChild(img);
        $(img).draggable({containment:'#myDiagramDiv'});
        }
</script>
```

How can I get that picture in my addimage1 function and set it as img.src?

My Script tag is inside a html tag, I don't know if that is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the most part your code is working just fine.  I think you may have a problem with the library you are trying to use.  Here is a similar working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/chrshawkes/4eaqpdsn/

```
<div id="myImage">

</div>

<script>
var url_1 = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d42ea6e005a4160211f7b1957ce0a09/?default=&s=64';

function addimage1() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = url_1;
  img.height = 50;
  img.width = 50;
  //optionally set a css class on the image
  var class_name = "foo";
  img.setAttribute("class", class_name);

  document.getElementById("myImage").appendChild(img);
}

addimage1();
</script>
```

Comment: Well yes, that works, but i want to get the picture from my static files.

Comment: are any of your static files working?  do you have {% load staticfiles %} at the top of the template?  If so, there is no reason you can't assign a javascript image variable using the django static way.  var url_1 = '{% static "assets/img/stolovi/2.jpg" %}';  I would check and see what url is being returned by that static keyword and see if there is a 404 file not found error

Comment: yes, all of them are working just fine, but this one wont.

Comment: are you getting a 404, have you checked the console to see if there is a javascript error occurring?

Comment: Yes i was getting a 404, thank you, I didn't know where to look, solved it.